# How can I set checkbox to checked state in a React Hook Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying out [React-Hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/)

The simple code for the checkbox is as below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm()
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data)
  console.log(errors)

  return (
    <div className='mx-auto justify-center p-32 flex'>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className='p-2'>
          <label htmlFor=''>January</label>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            placeholder='January'
            {...register('January', {})}
            className='mx-3'
            checked
          />
        </div>
        <div className='p-2'>
          <label htmlFor=''>February</label>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            placeholder='February'
            {...register('February', {})}
            className='mx-3'
          />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I can submit the form correctly but I have like the January checkbox to start off as a checked box but when I put 'checked' as shown in the code, I somehow could not 'uncheck' it.

I seem to be missing something and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: at first glance, you have just passed checked and no onChange to change it's state accordingly.

Comment: @Leviathan [`register()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) returns `onChange` and/or `onBlur` so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue with passing `checked` is that it takes control away from `useForm` to manage the checkbox. `useForm` [`register()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) uses change handlers (`onChange`/`onBlur`) to update the `checked` (or `value` for non-checkboxes) attributes of the actual DOM `<input>` element.

By passing the `checked` prop you are overriding the `checked` DOM attribute that is managed by `useForm`. This causes the checkbox to be unable to change state.

---

Now that I've cleared up why this issue happens let's move on to the solution. This can be solved in two ways:

1. [`useForm`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) allows you to pass a default values when you initially call the hook.

   ```
   const {
     register,
     handleSubmit,
     formState: { errors },
   } = useForm({ defaultValues: { January: true } });

   // ...

   <input
     type="checkbox"
     {...register("January")}
   />
   ```
2. Or use the [`defaultChecked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_properties_that_apply_only_to_elements_of_type_checkbox_or_radio) property of an `<input type="checkbox" />` this holds the initial checked value and doesn't override the current value like `checked` does.

   ```
   const {
     register,
     handleSubmit,
     formState: { errors },
   } = useForm();

   // ...

   <input
     type="checkbox"
     {...register("January")}
     defaultChecked
   />
   ```

Note that it's not a good idea to combine the two methods. Use one or the other. The `useForm` says the following in the [`defaultValues`](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#defaultValues) section:

> The `defaultValues` prop populates the entire form with default values. It supports both synchronous and asynchronous assignment of default values. While you can set an input's default value using `defaultValue` or `defaultChecked` [(as detailed in the official React documentation)](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input), it is **recommended** to use `defaultValues` for the entire form.

---

In the given scenario it's probably better to use an array of selected values `["January", "March"]` instead of an object `{ January: true, February: false, March: true }`.

You can get the array result by using an (empty) array as the default value, and registering the checkboxes under the same name. If any values are present inside the array, they will be checked by default. The values used in the array will match the checkbox `value` property.

```
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
  defaultValues: { months: ["January"] }
  // mark months as array and ^ check the checkbox with value "January"
});

// ...

// add the a `value` prop to the checkboxes
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value="January"
  {...register("months")}
/>
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value="February"
  {...register("months")}
/>
```

Comment: Great explanation! Do you know why `checked` and `onChange` is returned at all, isn't it supposed to be an uncontrolled input? I hoped the register() would only return the ref, that is how it seemed to be working in an earlier version of the lib :/.

Comment: @user3711421 You're correct. After reading a bit more of the documentation it seems that the library uses uncontrolled components (aka, no `checked` prop is provided to the `<input type="checkbox" />` JSX element). I've updated the explanation to better reflect this. This does not change the fact that passing `checked` yourself will override the `checked` state that is managed by `useForm`/`register` through the `onChange`/`onBlur` event handlers.

Comment: Thank you for the solution with the Array of selected values.
I noticed 1 downside of it.
If you have an array `currentUser = ["user", "admin"]` and you want to display a single checkbox `Is admin?` with value `admin`, checking and unchecking the checkbox wiped the whole Array (remove the **user**)

Comment: @Kosmonaft Yes, if there is no "user" checkbox in the form the value will be removed. Since the submit data represents the data in the form. If want to have some default value present like user you'll have to add on submit. `onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(evolve({ roles: prepend("user") }, data)))}`. I'm using the Ramda [`evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) and [`prepend`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#prepend) helper, to simplify immutable changes.

Comment: @Kosmonaft Here as a working example of what I described above. https://stackblitz.com/edit/71794831-3982562-02?file=src%2FApp.jsx

Answer (score 8):

if you are using react material ui  with react-hook-form here is a simplest way to make it work

```js
import {
  Box
  Checkbox,
  FormControlLabel,
} from '@mui/material'
...
const {
  handleSubmit,
  control,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
})
...

<Box>
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={`${dimension.id}-${dimension.name}`}
  defaultValue={false}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox checked={value} onChange={onChange} />
      }
    />
  )}
/>
</Box>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working with Mantine Checkbox too !

Answer (score 3):

The complete working code based on @3limin4tOr

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { months: ['January'] },
  })

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data)
  console.log(errors)

  return (
    <div className='mx-auto justify-center p-32 flex'>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className='p-2'>
          <label htmlFor=''>January</label>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            value='January'
            placeholder='January'
            {...register('months')}
            className='mx-3'
          />
        </div>
        <div className='p-2'>
          <label htmlFor=''>February</label>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            value='February'
            placeholder='February'
            {...register('months')}
            className='mx-3'
          />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find here input, checkbox, and radio in one field with React Hook form

```
import { useState } from "react";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { FormProvider, useForm, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

const ChooseCarType = () => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="field-rain">
          <input
            {...register("weather")}
            type="radio"
            value="rain"
            id="field-rain"
          />
          Rain
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="field-wind">
          <input
            {...register("weather")}
            type="radio"
            value="wind"
            id="field-wind"
          />
          Lots of wind
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="field-sun">
          <input
            {...register("weather")}
            type="radio"
            value="sun"
            id="field-sun"
          />
          Sunny
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const ChooseService = () => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" {...register("jan")} />
          Jan
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" {...register("feb")} />
          Feb
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" {...register("mar")} />
          Mar
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const UserData = () => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label>
          Username
          <input {...register("username")} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password
          <input {...register("password")} />
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <ChooseCarType />
        <ChooseService />
        <UserData />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```